# Models and forms in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, opencv, django-models, django-forms

Is forms and models run parallelly in  Django?
I've created a forms.py in my app and in that  forms.py I've created a loginform instead of forms.py I've created AbstractUser and registration table in models.py, then import this loginform to models.py(from user_app.forms import LoginView). Then in forms.py import the models.py AbstractUser class. (I've named this class as user_type .. from user_app.models import user_type).
I got this error

File "D:\PROJECT\Digital-Vehicle-Project\digi_vehicle\user_app\models.py", line 7, in 
from user_app.forms import LoginForm

File "D:\PROJECT\Digital-Vehicle-Project\digi_vehicle\user_app\forms.py", line 2, in

```
from user_app.models import user_type
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'user_type' from 'user_app.models' (D:\PROJECT\Digital-Vehicle-Project\digi_vehicle\user_app\models.py)

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }

    )
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = UserType
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_user', 'is_insurance', 'is_police', 'is_rto')
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser

from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
from django.db.models import CASCADE, BooleanField

from user_app.forms import LoginForm


class user_type(AbstractBaseUser):
    is_user = models.BooleanField('Is user', default=False)
    is_police = models.BooleanField('Is police', default=False)
    is_insurance = models.BooleanField('Is insurance', default=False)
    is_rto = models.BooleanField('Is rto', default=False)


class Owner(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    login_id = models.ForeignKey(LoginForm, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    aadhar_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    photo = models.FileField()
    mobile = models.IntegerField()
    licence = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Comment: You forgot to add the error message.

Comment: sorry for that. Now I've added

Comment: What is `user_type` ? A model class?  A function?  A field on a model class?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: user_type is a class name

Answer (score 0):

In forms.py you need to add the import of the UserType class like this

```
from user_app.models import UserType
```

Not like this

```
from user_app.models import user_type
```

Comment: I have done that also. But the error repeating, I've changed that AbstracUser class name different times but it's not working. Is there is any problem to run forms.py and models.py in parallel?